# asp.net and c# also use javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a multiline text box for sending messages to students, i enter the roll numbers comma separated like 1,2,3 like this .when i enter one it has to display roll number is name like a tool tip.

[image]

my question is when i enter roll number 1 in multiline textbox it has to dispay roll number one student name from databse ,next i put comm and enter the 2 , it has to display 2nd roll nmber student name in a label

Answer (score -1):

First of all I don't know if I get your question right, but in a multiline textbox everything you put is text. So if you put 1,2,3 it won't display any name from the database because it's just text and not some reference to a value. Also you don't make any call to your database to get the name (if I get your description right).
I think you have to reconsider your choice and put another field in your form in which the user puts either the names either the numbers.

Comment: sir i have a student database it contains rollnumber ,name fathername dob etc, for sending a mess to parents about absence of a student , i created a multiline textbox , in that i will enter his roll number , for shake of confirmation  in a label it has to display his name , next i will put second absentee student roll number it has to display his name , after finishing i will sand same sms to all the students ,

Comment: I think instead of putting the number inside the textbox you can make another filed in your form which will provide the names of the students (for example a dropdown list and as id's you can use your roll numbers), because everything you put inside a textbox it's concsidered as a text. So when you do the query to the database you can assosiate the number from the dropdwon list item to the numbers in the database to get the users